# Bad URI exceptions for all requests to rails server which pass nested params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get "bad URI" exceptions for all requests to Rails server which pass nested params e.g. /products/new?product[name]=Dummy. So /products/new?param=value works. The problem appears only in development environment.

The server log shows only 1 line for the whole request: [2015-02-18 10:28:35] ERROR bad URI `/products/new?product[name]=Dummy'.

And I'm using Ruby 2.2.0, Rails 4.2.0 and Webrick 1.3.1.

What can I do?

Regards

Mathias

Answer (score 1):

I was using ruby-2.2.0-preview1 which fails at this code:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI('http://localhost:3000/products/new?product[name]=Dummy')
```

Switched to a stable ruby 2.0 version and now it works.